# Acessar google Analytics via API PHP [Impossível ?]

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, php-cli

Olá,

Estou tentando a dois dias encontrar uma forma de conectar a API do google analytics via PHP (vou utilizar em modo CLI) para obter dados de uma determinada visão.

O problema é que a api é EXTREMAMENTE CONFUSA e todos os exemplos que encontro e um dia funcionaram já não funcionam mais (ora porque uma determinada classe não é distribuida no SDK, ora porque simplesmente o método não existe na API).

**Por favor,** se alguém tem um exemplo real que funcione de acordo com as últimas versões poderia compartilhar link/código para entender onde estou errando ?

Eu já li várias documentações mas os objetos servidos nos documentos simplesmente não existem no SDK. Agradeço imensamente quem puder contribuir...

Answer (score 1):

Também estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação pra acessar esta api.

Não recomento usar PHP, bem que eu também queria muito rs.

Mais este aqui é um exemplo que testei e deu certo.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer um teste...mas ainda vou insistir no PHP rsrsrs

Comment: Se tiver sucesso, avise-me, tô aqui na Luta com JS. Acabei de postar uma quest, rsrs ! Abraços.

Comment: Tambem nao consegui avançar, estou voltando para a prancheta e tentando tudo de novo